# Upload 300MB or more CSV file to GCP storage bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, storage, infrastructure, google-cloud-storage, csv

I am trying to upload a 3GB CSV file to Google Cloud Storage Bucket but every time I try it only processing 295.5MB and uploads 295.5MB. Why is this? I have set my bucket size limit to 15GB.

Comment: hey @jarvis crypter , to help you further I would need some more info. can you let me know how did you set limit of 15GB on your bucket? as far as I know there is no way to set a limit for a bucket. can you let me know how are you uploading your file (gsutil, drag and drop, programmatically ...etc)? can you check your project logs and see if there are some usefull logs that explain the issue?

Comment: Where you able to solve this issue? If not, kindly let us know more details regarding your case to troubleshoot this issue further. As @MethkalKhalawi mentioned, the is no way to set a limit for a bucket. The [size limit](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploads-downloads) of a single file to be uploaded is 5TB. Let us know if you try to upload via Console, gsutil, Client Libraries, or through an API.

Comment: In general, a good practice when uploading large files is using [resumable uploads](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/resumable-uploads), that will allow you to resume from the point the upload was interrupted in case of network failure.